# what is this.element in a jquery function?

Tags: jquery

I was reading an excellent explanation of the jQuery UI combobox by Jörn Zaefferer ([here's the link](http://www.learningjquery.com/2010/06/a-jquery-ui-combobox-under-the-hood)).

The fourth line of code reads `var select = this.element.hide()`

Jörn says:

> The var select references the select element on which the combobox gets applied. To replace the select with the text input, the select is hidden.

I am learning jQuery now, and I don't recall seeing **this.element** before. How is it different that just **this**?

Comment: ... And, where the element-name?  `$(X).html()` shows content of the element, but not the element itself!

Comment: HERE: `var elementName = $(this).get(0).tagName.toLowerCase();`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Inside a widget, "this" refers to the widget object itself, which contains a property "element". That "element" points to html element for which that widget has been applied.

Comment: Thanks, I thought this might be the case. So a widget is actually an object in its own right. As opposed to, say, a plugin, where "this" would refer to the object you are calling it on.

Answer (score 7):

You can think of it like this.

```
this.element // is just normal jquery object

// for example
var element = $('.current-selected-dropdown');

// and then put this together inside ui object
this.element = element
```

I'm not sure if this would help you.

```
var Dropdown = {
    element: null,
    _init: function() {

        // here is the same this.element that you referred to. 
        this.element = $('.dropdown');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The this being referred here is probably not the query object, and this.element has been used to cache the query object.